# How to decide whether a number in a dictionary is a str or float?

Tags: python

I am asking this because I saw a dictionary produced from two different sources, in which one number is a float, and the same number is a string.

data = {'name': 'jack', 'confidence': '0.95'}

The 'confidence' is a float in once case, and a str in another case. Why is that?

```
conf = data.get('confidence')
```

Comment: because one source decided to give you strings, other decided to give you floats. I dont really see a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conf = data.get('confidence')
try:
  conf = float(conf)
except:
  pass
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how they decided to store value in the dict. But if you want to access the value, `conf = float(data.get('confidence'))` might be good for your use.

Answer (score 1):

Values in a dictionary surrounded by quotes are strings. '0.95' is a string, but 0.95 is a float. You can use the isinstance built-in function:

```py
conf = data.get('confidence')
if isinstance(conf, str):
    pass
elif isinstance(conf, float):
    pass
```